# Loading Protocol Buffer From File Does Not Succeed

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, ifstream

I want to load Google Protocol Buffer encoded data from a file via "**ParseFromIstream**". But this call simply returns false (no additional error information available?) and the data is only read partially (e.g. various sub-messages are empty).

When I load the data to memory beforehand and then use "**ParseFromArray**", the parser succeeds and all data is present.

I would like to find out why **ParseFromIstream** fails and how to fix this behavior.

Here's my example code:

```
// Test 1 - read data from memory -> works

// Read data from file to memory
int numBytes;
char* bytes = ReadFileToMemory(L"C:\\MyData.bin", &numBytes);

// Parse protobuf
mytest::ProtoRoot root1{};
bool loadFromMemoryOk = root1.ParseFromArray(bytes, numBytes); // OK
// Parsing worked, root1 contains all data



// Test 2 - read data from file -> does not work

// Open file stream
std::ifstream ifs(L"C:\\MyData.bin", std::ifstream::in);

// Parse protobuf
mytest::ProtoRoot root2{};
bool loadFromFileOk  = root2.ParseFromIstream(&ifs); // Not OK
// Parsing failed, root2 only contains some data, most fields are empty
```

Comment: `char* bytes = ReadFileToMemory(...)` is a code smell. What is this `ReadFileToMemory` function? What does it do? Why doesn't it return some kind of C++ container? And why do you pass objects by pointer rather than by reference?

Comment: By the way, are you sure that your file stream have opened successfully? (And there's no need for the `std::ifstream::in` argument, it's implied for input streams.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It does exactly what the name says: it reads a file to memory (byte array). But this is IMHO out of scope, since the protobuf parsing functions are what this question are about.

Comment: I agree with @Someprogrammerdude, this function might be the cause of the problem. Also how do you know how many bytes to read from the file? Depending on the values serialized the length of the protobuf data may very. Is there just one message or multiple messages in the file?

Comment: It might be unrelated to the problem at hand, but that function could still be full of other problems. For example, who is responsible for freeing the memory allocated by the function? The function *do* allocate memory? Does it properly terminate the data as a string, or it it just a binary blob of bytes? And most importantly, why does it return a pointer instead of a `std::string` (if it creates a string) or a `std::vector<std::byte>` (for arbitrary binary data)? Like I said, it's a bad code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
std::ifstream ifs("C:\\MyData.bin", std::ios::binary);
```

The emphasis being on the `std::ios::binary` part. Protobuf files are binary and not text, so you want to open your input file stream in binary mode.

For more information, see e.g.: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/FILE#Binary_and_text_modes